# Core Data - Breaking A Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a Patient entity and a List entity. A Patient can belong to several different lists and a list can have several different patients.

Say I have a patient who belongs to 3 lists (A, B, C). I want to remove the patient from lists A & B. I do not want to delete lists A & B themselves though obviously. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Tim's answer above is technically correct, it seems like quite a bit of code to me.

I would assume that to remove a patient from the list, you already know that list and have a reference to it at the time you want to remove the patient. Therefore, the code can be as simple as:

```
id myPatient = ...;
id myList = ...;
[[myPatient mutableSetValueForKey:@"lists"] removeObject:myList];
```

This is of course assuming that your relationships are bi-directional. If they are not then I strongly suggest you make them bi-directional.

Lastly, because this is a many to many relationship, you can execute the above code in either direction.

```
[[myList mutableSetValueForKey:@"patients"] removeObject:myPatient];
```

### update

Then the code is even simplier:

```
[myPatient setLists:nil];
```

That will remove the patient from all lists.

Comment: I am essentially trying to "discharge" a patient (therefore remove it from all active lists). I have a reference to the patient NSManagedObject but I don't have a reference to any of the lists it belongs to.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think it could be that simple. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the previous approach and it worked with one-to-many relationship . In case of many-to-many relationship between entities A & B I have a breaking entity C. I used to remove the object from entity C that connects both A&B. But I can not see the results unless the record is re-fetched from database. Is there something I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: Sarah, it is best to ask this as a separate question so that you can explain the situation in more detail as I am having a hard time picturing what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for you replay , I have posted a separate question on the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910670/core-data-breaking-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 1):

So in order to model this relationship, you have a many-to-many relationship between Patient and List. Let's say that in Core Data, this is represented by a `patients` relationship on List, with the inverse `lists` relationship on Patient. Furthermore let's assume that List has some property `name` with the name of the list, as an NSString.

In order to "break" the relationship (remove a Patient from some Lists), you'll have to have a reference to the Patient NSManagedObject that is to be removed, and the Lists you want to remove that Patient from. Then, all that remains to be done is get a mutable set of the patients for each list, and remove the desired patient:

```
// Assuming you have some PatientManagedObject *patient:
NSSet *patientLists = [patient lists]; // Set of ListManagedObjects
for(ListManagedObject list in patientLists) {
    if([[list name] isEqualToString:@"A"] || [[list name] isEqualToString:@"B"]){
        // Now you have to build the set of patients without this patient
        NSMutableSet *listPatients = [list mutableSetValueForKey:@"patients"];
        [listPatients removeObject:patient];
    }
}
```

For more data, see [the relevant Core Data documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-212651).

Comment: According to the "To-many relationships" section in that documentation, it would seem you could just do [list removePatientObject:patient]